# converting an if+or+indirect function to vba

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, excel-indirect

Hello im trying to convert this function:

```
=IF(OR(INDIRECT("'sheet1'!C8")="Nouveau locataire",INDIRECT("'sheet1'!C8")="Décès"),CELL("contents",INDIRECT("'sheet1'!B8")),"")
```

to something similar to :

```
Sub if_orfuction()

Dim i As Integer
j = 2

    For i = 2 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

        If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = "Nouveau Locataire" Or Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = "Décès" Then

            Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(j, 1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
            j = j + 1

        End If

    Next i


End Sub
```

how can i implement the indirect in the fuction?

Comment: Does sheet1'!C8 or sheet1'!B8 contain worksheet as well as cell reference or can the cell address be assumed to be on Sheet1?

Comment: The cell address is on Sheet1. i just need it to refer to the cell dynamically so if i delete rows in Sheet1, the code still refers to the cell in the same row.

Comment: Would `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(8, 3)` not do it for you?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to "filter" the range on sheet 1-> copy it -> paste values to sheet 3???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
Sub if_orfuction()

    Dim i As long,  j as long

    j = 2
    with workSheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 2 To .cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

            If .range(.range("B" & i).Value).Value = "Nouveau Locataire" Or _
               .range(.range("B" & i).Value).Value = "Décès" Then

                workSheets("Sheet3").Cells(j, "A") = .Cells(i, "A").Value
                j = j + 1

            End If

        Next i
    end with

End Sub
```

Comment: this is giving me run-time error 1004 for the .range lines